# OpenCart show weight in product block

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am currently working on an ecommerce website using opencart, trying to show the weight of each product, in product details template it works, however, when I do the same thing to the product block, it shows undefined variable. This is the site [KCityMart](http://kcitymart.com)

So what I did to show the weight in product details page is this

in file **catalog/controller/product/product.php** I added this

```
$data['weight'] = $this->weight->format($product_info['weight'],$product_info['weight_class_id']);
```

and in **/catalog/view/theme/theme/template/product/product.tpl** I added this

```
        <ul class="volume">
          <?php if ($weight > 0) { ?>
          <li><?php echo $weight; ?></li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

and it works. But, when I tried to add this to **/catalog/view/theme/theme/template/common/product/default.tpl** it shows "undefined variable" error.

What could be the problem? Which part did I miss?

Any input from you all will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is default.tpl file ? If it's new file then you need to create controller file for it and then do the same thing which you are performed in product controller.

Assigned weight varible in  **catalog/controller/product/default.php** (**Note:** *If you did not created default.php controller then you need to create*) then add following code

```
> $data['weight'] = $this->weight->format($product_info['weight'],$product_info['weight_class_id']);
```

and in **/catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/default.tpl** 
add following code in above file.

```
<ul class="volume">
      <?php if ($weight > 0) { ?>
      <li><?php echo $weight; ?></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```